# Liferay: Controlling form validators at runtime via JavaScript

Tags: validation, liferay

I am using Liferay 6.2 and built-in form validators using AUI taglib, ie:

```
<aui:input ... > 
    ... 
    <aui:validator name="number" errorMessage="Enter number" />
</aui:input>
```

Is there any way to disable and re-enable the validation at runtime (after portlet is displayed) via JavaScript?

The only solution I thought of was to re-implement all validators as custom validators with same functionality and on/off switch - this looks like a lot of work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did use the suggested method to reimplement the validators as custom validators, it's not a too big work but it would be really great not to have to do it.

Looking deeper in some liferay component I found that the Liferay.auto_field did remove validators and add it back when required. The code doing it look like this: (https://github.com/liferay/liferay-portal/blob/master/portal-web/docroot/html/js/liferay/auto_fields.js#L219)

```
var errors = formValidator.errors;
rules = formValidator.get('rules');
node.all('input, select, textarea').each(function(item, index) {
    var name = item.attr('name') || item.attr('id');
    if (rules && rules[name]) {
    deletedRules[name] = rules[name];
    delete rules[name];
    }
    if (errors && errors[name]) {
    delete errors[name];
    }
});
```

I didn't try to do it myself, but this should work. Important to note, to get the formValidator you need to (can see on https://github.com/liferay/liferay-portal/blob/master/portal-web/docroot/html/js/liferay/auto_fields.js#L501)

```
Liferay.Form.get(formId).formValidator
```

Comment: Thank. Will try it in following days and let you know the results.